# Comment dit-on en français "what's your email" ?

Tags: questions, pronoms-interrogatifs

Comment dit-on en français "what's your email"?

Quelle est la différence entre "quel est ton e-mail" et "c'est quoi ton e-mail" ?

Answer (score 2):

> What's your email (address)?

can be interpreted by:

> Quelle est votre (adresse) e-mail ?
>
> Quelle est ton (adresse) e-mail ?

The difference is based on whether you address someone as vous (that is, vouvoyer) or as tu (tutoyer).

> C'est quoi ton e-mail ?

[**EDIT** (thanks @jlliagre)]

is asking the same thing. The difference is that this way of posing questions is slightly colloquial in spoken French and certainly anyway the most usual way people will ask this question to people they already tutoient.

Suggested reading:

[Quand tutoyer - Quand vouvoyer ?](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-11009.php)

[Tutoyer ou vouvoyer ? - Culture](http://parlons-francais.tv5monde.com/webdocumentaires-pour-apprendre-le-francais/Memos/Culture/p-266-lg0-Tutoyer-ou-vouvoyer-.htm)

[Registres de langue](http://keepschool.com/fiches-de-cours/college/francais/registres-langue.html)

[Registres de langue, II](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/figures-de-style/niveaux-de-langage.php)

[Glossaire informatique](http://www.celog.fr/cpi/termino_01.htm)

Comment: Stating that **c'est quoi ton e-mail** is "very informal" is exaggerated. I would just say it is slightly colloquial in spoken French and certainly anyway the most usual way people will ask this question to people they already *tutoient*.

Answer (score 2):

1. Il n'existe pas un terme unique pour email; le français a le terme assez courant et recommandé « courriel » dont on trouve la  [définition](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/courriel) suivante : « Alors que "mail" ou "e-mail" serait le medium du message électronique, le courriel serait son contenu».

On voit qu'il n'y a pas d'usage bien établi pour l'instant; on ne trouve pas ces termes dans le dictionnaire académique.

Le terme le plus long est « **adresse électronique** »; il est sans ambigüité et ne peut pas être contesté sur le plan de l'usage.

On peut utiliser des combinaisons de mots qui ne vont pas à contresens, par exemple, « **adresse courriel** », « **adresse mail** », « **adresse email** »  et même  « **email** » et « **mail** ».

Étant donné que ce qui correspond au message et que l'on appelle un « email » en anglais  devrait être traduit par « courriel », si l'on veut rester fidèle au directives nationales en ce qui concerne la langue française on devrait dire « adresse courriel » mais comme une majorité de français ne tient pas compte de ces directives, on a encore le choix des autres termes.

2. Pour dire « What's your email? » you say in standard language either of the following.

   - Quelle est votre/ton adresse courriel?, « Quel est votre/ton email? »

« C'est quoi votre email? » est du langage assez gauche que des personnes travaillant dans le commerce ou un service public n'utiliseront pas souvent; c'est une forme qui en dehors d'une utilisation entre amis peut paraitre assez grossière. Donc d'autres façons de demander seront utilisées par les gens qui veulent éviter toute gaucherie ou termes abrupts; les possibilités suivantes sont seulement quelques exemples.

> - Pourriez-vous me dire votre adresse courriel?
> - Votre email s'il vous plait…
> - Avez-vous un email?
> - Il me faudrait votre email…
> - Donnez-moi votre email svp.
> - Et maintenant votre email… (*à la suite d'autres demandes*)
> - Voulez-vous me donner votre email?